# Можно ли создать метод создатель фабрики

Tags: java, hibernate

Можно ли создать метод создатель фабрики сессий и сессий для Hibernate или каждый раз надо писать такой код ?

```
 SessionFactory factory;
        Session session;
 factory = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
                .addAnnotatedClass(href.class)
                .addAnnotatedClass(car.class)
                .buildSessionFactory();
        session = factory.getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
```

Я пробовал создать оверлоад метод но не понимаю какой тип объекта надо передавать в параметр метода,
моя неудачная попытка

```
public SessionFactory createFactory(Configuration config){
    SessionFactory factory = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
            .addAnnotatedClass(config.class)
            .addAnnotatedClass(car.class)
            .buildSessionFactory();
    return factory;
}
```

Comment: я прошу прощения, а в чем именно попытка неудачна? Вроде бы из метода createFactory нормально возвращается factory типа SessionFactory?

Comment: SessionFactory можно, точнее нужно, создать один раз при старте приложения (или при необходимости) и потом ее использовать для создания сессий.

Comment: @S.H. компилятор ругается, требует создать такой класс , нужен тип обьекта передаваемый в параметры метода который символизирует класс.

Comment: Тогда, наверное, Вам лучше добавить эту информацию в вопрос... Там есть редактирование вопросов. Нужна ошибка, код вызова и Ваши соображения на эту тему :-)